# Upgrading Artifactory from 3.2.1.1 to 5.4.6 fails (WAR file only installation)

Tags: artifactory

We had tomcat running just artifactory.war and it was all working great and we were using Active Directory too. However, after upgrading the war(s) to version `5.4.6` it fails to load.

We did check if it has single repository types using the Python tool (`https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-scripts/blob/master/4.x-migration/packageCheck.py`). We use `apache-tomcat-8.5.20`, `jdk1.8.0_144`, and `jfrog-artifactory-oss-5.4.6.zip` on Windows (7 and 2008 have the same outcome)

The Tomcat was modified to use proper `%JDK_HOME%` and `%ARTIFACTORY_HOME%`
Also, `<Host>` element was updated with `startStopThreads="2"` in `server.xml`. 
The `%TOMCAT_HOME%\lib` folder contains `derby-10.11.1.1.jar`, 
`artifactory.war` and `access.war` were copied to Tomcat's `webapps` folder

When we started the Tomcat the migration happened and all the repos are converted without an error, the failure is:

```
artifactory.log  

2017-09-25 17:04:09,772 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.a.ArtifactoryAccessClientConfigStore:472) - Using Access Server URL: http://localhost:8080/access (bundled) source: detected
2017-09-25 17:04:11,484 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.a.AccessServiceImpl:233) - Waiting for access server...
2017-09-25 17:04:21,406 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.a.AccessServiceImpl:243) - Got response from Access server after 9921 ms, continuing.
2017-09-25 17:04:21,636 [art-init] [WARN ] (o.j.a.c.AccessClientBootstrap:92) - Access admin credentials not found, using default admin credentials.
2017-09-25 17:04:21,985 [art-init] [ERROR] (o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener:97) - Application could not be initialized: HTTP response status 401:{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","detail":"Bad credentials","message":"HTTP 401 Unauthorized"}]}
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.configure(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:222) ~[artifactory-web-application-5.4.6.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.access$2(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:184) ~[artifactory-web-application-5.4.6.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener$1.run(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:93) ~[artifactory-web-application-5.4.6.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Failed to initialize bean 'org.artifactory.security.access.AccessService'.; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to generate service admin token using bootstrap credentials.
    at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.refresh(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:230) ~[artifactory-core-5.4.6.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.<init>(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:114) ~[artifactory-core-5.4.6.jar:na]
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to generate service admin token using bootstrap credentials.
    at org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientBootstrap.createAndStoreServiceAdminToken(AccessClientBootstrap.java:110) ~[access-client-core-2.0.2.jar:na]
```

We reached to jFrog and Aaron from jFrog has suggested it might be because of this bug. https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-14839

So, we went ahead and deleted the `admin` entry from `access_users` table using embedded Derby JDBC driver from `%HOME%/.jfrog-access/data/derby` as suggested. We also placed `bootstrap.creds` file in the `%HOME%/.jfrog-access/etc`.

```
bootstrap.creds

admin=plaintextadminpasswordhere
```

Later we also added 2 properties to `artifactory.system.properties`

```
artifactory.system.properties
artifactory.access.server.bundled=true
artifactory.access.client.serverUrl.override=http://localhost:8080/access
```

as suggested in related issue https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-14477 (although it seemed not to be the issue)

When we started one more time the `bootstrap.creds` file got processed (it disappeared) and the new `admin` entry was created in the `access_users` table. Nevertheless, the outcome is almost exactly the same:

```
2017-09-25 18:25:42,689 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.a.ArtifactoryAccessClientConfigStore:472) - Using Access Server URL: http://localhost:8080/access (bundled) source: system property
2017-09-25 18:25:43,600 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.a.AccessServiceImpl:233) - Waiting for access server...
2017-09-25 18:25:54,667 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.a.AccessServiceImpl:243) - Got response from Access server after 11065 ms, continuing.
2017-09-25 18:25:55,434 [art-init] [WARN ] (o.j.a.c.AccessClientBootstrap:92) - Access admin credentials not found, using default admin credentials.
2017-09-25 18:25:55,980 [art-init] [ERROR] (o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener:97) - Application could not be initialized: HTTP response status 401:{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","detail":"Bad credentials","message":"HTTP 401 Unauthorized"}]}
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.configure(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:222) ~[artifactory-web-application-5.4.6.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.access$2(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:184) ~[artifactory-web-application-5.4.6.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener$1.run(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:93) ~[artifactory-web-application-5.4.6.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Failed to initialize bean 'org.artifactory.security.access.AccessService'.; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to generate service admin token using bootstrap credentials.
    at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.refresh(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:230) ~[artifactory-core-5.4.6.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.<init>(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:114) ~[artifactory-core-5.4.6.jar:na]
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to generate service admin token using bootstrap credentials.
    at org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientBootstrap.createAndStoreServiceAdminToken(AccessClientBootstrap.java:110) ~[access-client-core-2.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientBootstrap.bootstrapServiceAdminToken(AccessClientBootstrap.java:79) ~[access-client-core-2.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientBootstrap.<init>(AccessClientBootstrap.java:42) ~[access-client-core-2.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.initAccessService(AccessServiceImpl.java:227) ~[artifactory-core-5.4.6.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.initIfNeeded(AccessServiceImpl.java:216) ~[artifactory-core-5.4.6.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.init(AccessServiceImpl.java:211) ~[artifactory-core-5.4.6.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.artifactory.storage.fs.lock.aop.LockingAdvice.invoke(LockingAdvice.java:76) ~[artifactory-storage-common-5.4.6.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.init(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.refresh(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:228) ~[artifactory-core-5.4.6.jar:na]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientHttpException: HTTP response status 401:{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","detail":"Bad credentials","message":"HTTP 401 Unauthorized"}]}
    at org.jfrog.access.client.http.AccessHttpClient.createRestResponse(AccessHttpClient.java:312) ~[access-client-core-2.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.jfrog.access.client.http.AccessHttpClient.restCall(AccessHttpClient.java:299) ~[access-client-core-2.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.jfrog.access.client.http.AccessHttpClient.createToken(AccessHttpClient.java:133) ~[access-client-core-2.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.jfrog.access.client.token.TokenClientImpl.create(TokenClientImpl.java:36) ~[access-client-core-2.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientBootstrap.createAndStoreServiceAdminToken(AccessClientBootstrap.java:103) ~[access-client-core-2.0.2.jar:na]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
2017-09-25 18:25:56,687 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] [ERROR] (o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryFilter:188) - Artifactory failed to initialize: Context is null
```

Any suggestions what we should try next?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

We had some problems migrating to Artifactory 5.4 at my workplace too: [RTFACT-14690](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-14690)

My (limited) understanding is that the refactoring and split from artifactory.war into artifactory.war and access.war, starting from 5.4.0, opened a lot of issues for migrations.

Can you do the migration in two steps?

- Migrate from 3.2.1.1 to 5.3.X
- Migrate from 5.3.X to 5.4.6

This worked for us and worked around our upgrade problem nicely.

Comment: Will try this if no more ideas will surface, was thinking about it too. Thanks a lot, it's good to know someone else tried it and it worked!

Comment: Tried 5.3.2 and it works without issues but 5.5.1 applied after it fails with the same problem FYI

Comment: Didn't know 5.5.0 was out yet :-)
Did you try again all the steps from your question (`artifactory.system.properties`, `bootstrap.creds`) on 5.5.1?
If that is already the case, the last idea I have is to do a system export of 5.3.2, install a fresh 5.5.1 instance and do a system import from the 5.3.2 export.

Comment: FYI tried 5.3.2 and it works however 5.5.1 on top of this fails with the same issue. For now we will use 5.3.2 and will wait for those bugs to be fixed before attempting to upgrade.